# Why overwritten ListView transitions don't work?

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I want to override the default transtionion of miy ListView control which is bound to an observable collection. I want to use the more fluit transitions when adding / removing items to it or setting it completely new.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<ListView 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredNewsDealsList}" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DealItemTemplateStretch}"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyleStretch}"
    Grid.Row="5" Padding="40,10,25,0" 
    IsSwipeEnabled="false"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    ItemClick="itemGridView_ItemClick"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
            <RepositionThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
</ListView>
```

I have also tried to do realize the transtitions in the ItemsPanel but that doesn't work either:

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal">
            <WrapGrid.ChildrenTransitions>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <EntranceThemeTransition/>
                    <RepositionThemeTransition/>
                </TransitionCollection>
            </WrapGrid.ChildrenTransitions>
        </WrapGrid>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: I'd check some other places for transitions since there are many where these could be set or overwritten... One is `ItemsPanel`/`Panel.ChildrenTransitions`.

Comment: Hey Filip. Thanks for your answer! I tried that (see my edited post) but it doesn't work either. Do you know other places where to implement transitions?